# Как в python сделать ввод нужного числа?

Tags: python

Как сделать что бы в python, пользователь вводил то число которое нужно? Например: нужно что бы пользователь ввёл (1,2,3,4, или 5), что то одно. Если вводить больше или меньше, то его опять просят ввести (1,2,3,4 или 5)

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    i = int(input())
    if 0 < i < 6:
        print("OK")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ent = int(input("Enter num: \n"))
while ent != range(1,5):
    if ent < 1:
        print("Введите значение больше")
        ent = int(input("Enter num: \n"))
    elif ent > 5:
        print("Введите значение меньше")
        ent = int(input("Enter num: \n"))
    else:
        print("Значение входит в требуемый диапазон")
        break
```

Comment: `ent != range(1,5)` замените на `True`.Ввод числа поставьте в начало цикла, а остальные `input` уберите

Comment: `ent` - число, оно никогда не будет равно `range(1,5)`